# Shibboleth 4 Jetty Invalid SNI Issue

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, shibboleth

I setup a local shibboleth IdP 4.3 instance and had to use fully qualified names for the server post setup.  When trying to use the fully qualified name for the entityID / URL, I am getting the below error message in Shibboleth.  In the jetty-ssl-context.xml I disable the Sni checking but still getting this error.  Is there a way to turn this off in the IdP or another place to update the URL / name so fully qualified names can be used?

```
HTTP ERROR 400 Invalid SNI
URI:    /idp/shibboleth
STATUS: 400
MESSAGE:    Invalid SNI
SERVLET:    -
CAUSED BY:  org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
Caused by:
org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer.customize(SecureRequestCustomizer.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer.customize(SecureRequestCustomizer.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1078)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out.  In the main jetty configuration for the install, outside the jetty-base/etc config elements, had to disable the Sni host checking in the jetty-ssl.xml and jetty-ssl-context.xml files then this is working for the fully qualified names.

Nick